# Google Sheets Summary of other sheets (based on list of sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, sum

I have a googlesheet with multiple base sheets : Base1, Base2, Base3 etc. which could vary over time. (Add a new base, remove a base etc.)
I have a summary sheet. The summary sheet and Base Sheets are identical.

In the summary sheet I want cell

```
B2 = Base1!B2 + Base2!B2 + Base3!B2 and so on
```

But I want it to populate from the list of Bases in the Bases sheet
what I tried is

```
=SUM(indirect(Bases!$A$1:$A$3&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),true))
```

But it only takes on the first Base's values.

This works in excel though as expected, but not in google sheets.

I dont want to update the summary sheet's formalas each time I add or remove a base.

Here is a dummy mockup
[link to sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uUu5nqr7zNp3ufdDJ_wTI6Jc6sMs_c4ISrxCgEH7YF4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`REDUCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597?hl=en), like this:

```cpp
=REDUCE(,Bases!A1:A3,LAMBDA(sum,tab,ARRAYFORMULA(sum+INDIRECT(tab&"!B2:M23"))))
```

This formula produces the results for the whole table so you don't have to drag it.